# Поиск координат объекта на отфильтрованной картинке

Tags: python, изображения, opencv, pillow, координаты

Есть отфильтрованное изображение без лишнего шума. Возникли проблемы с нахождением объекта на картинке **даже** на черном фоне. Надо найти скорее не координаты объекта, а координаты области, в которой преобладает НЕ черный цвет. Надеюсь на вашу помощь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот здесь https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/
собраны методы OpenCV. 
А вообще, люди сюда приходят с проблемным кодом, а не с проблемными идеями.

Comment: найдите координаты всех не черных пикселей, затем найдите среднее по x и y, например

Comment: Приведите свой код и напишите, что конкретно у вас не получается.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2

im=cv2.imread('f0tiH.png')
im_gray=cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bw=cv2.threshold(im_gray, 19, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
retval, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(bw, connectivity=8)
x,y,w,h,s=stats[1,:]
cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), ( x+w, y+h),(0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.imwrite('name.png', im)
```

1. Бинаризируем.
2. Находим связную компоненту (одна).
3. Считываем ее
   координаты и выделяем объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Рисунок до обработки Python с OpenCV]

Простая программа Python с OpenCV по нахождению вершин полигонов для этого рисунка:

```
# import the required library 
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


# read the image 
img = cv2.imread('corner1.png') 

# convert image to gray scale image 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

# detect corners with the goodFeaturesToTrack function. 
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 27, 0.01, 10) 
corners = np.int0(corners) 

# we iterate through each corner,  
# making a circle at each point that we think is a corner. 
for i in corners: 
    x, y = i.ravel() 
    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, 255, -1) 

plt.imshow(img), plt.show()
```

Comment: при чем тут вершины полигонов?